# Prevent chrome helper from listening ports

Tags: google-chrome, mac

How can I prevent Chrome from listening ports? It pops a dialog saying that `Do you want the application “Google Chrome Helper.app” to accept incoming network connections?`

I'm getting this dialog on every startup, how can I avoid this permanently?

Comment: Does [this post](https://super-unix.com/superuser/how-to-stop-the-mac-from-asking-to-accept-incoming-network-connections/) help with the problem?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? This looks very much like an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Helper is the 'glue' between Chrome & its plugin structure. If you don't want the plugins, disable or remove them. If you don't want helper to connect, disable it too, but note that you will also lose functionality. See https://chromeready.com/6993/what-is-google-chrome-helper-and-how-to-disable-it/

Comment: I am having the same problem, posted https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/441744/getting-asked-if-i-want-to-allow-or-deny-incoming-connections-on-the-google-chro What extensions are you running? Privacy Badger seems to be causing ti for me.

Comment: Also, using lsof, chrome doesn't seem to be listening on any ports when I get this dialogue. Try disable all your extensions, then re-enable them to see whay causes it.

Answer (score 0):

A helpful advice might be found in the article
[What Is Google Chrome Helper, and Why Is It Hogging My CPU Cycles?](https://www.wired.com/2014/10/google-chrome-helper/)

> Disabling Helper's auto-helping is easy, and it won't prevent you from
> using plug-ins. You'll just have to opt in to view plug-in content on
> a case-by-case basis. Deactivating it isn't entirely intuitive,
> though—there's no mention of the Helper outside of your Activity
> Monitor and forum complaints. You’ll have to dig a couple of levels
> deep into your Chrome settings.
>
> First, shut down all your Chrome windows without quitting the program.
> In the Chrome menu, go to “Preferences,” scroll all the way down in
> the menu, and click on “Show advanced settings…” The first item in the
> expanded advanced settings list will be “Privacy,” and click on the
> “Content Settings” button right under that. About halfway down the
> content settings list is a “Plug-ins” entry, which will likely be set
> to “Run automatically.” Instead, select “Click to play.”
>
> This is essentially the same thing as configuring email to load images
> only when you click a “load images” link. Any embedded Flash, Java,
> Quicktime, DivX, or Silverlight content on a webpage will appear as a
> grayed-out space until you click on it to load the player and the
> content.

Comment: That article is a long way out of date - note 'Flash, Java, Quicktime, DivX, Silverlight' etc which have mostly been gone for years.

Comment: @Tetsujin: I don't have a Mac to check if it's still valid. What do you think?

Comment: I don't really use Chrome myself [I don't trust any company whose prime business model is to sell advertising;) but it looks like it's completely changed layout since then. Have a look at https://chromeready.com/6993/what-is-google-chrome-helper-and-how-to-disable-it/ instead.

Comment: It's not valid, the disable unsandboxed plugins is completely gone.

Answer (score 0):

I get this dialog too.

First of all, use sudo lsof -i -nP | grep LISTEN | grep :$PORT to determine if it actually is listening on any ports. All I ever see is remoted, so I don't think there is actually an incoming connection triggering this. As stated in [this post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/441744/getting-asked-if-i-want-to-allow-or-deny-incoming-connections-on-the-google-chro), it's likely that the app is checking it's own integrity, causing the dialog to appear. For me, privacy badger seems to be triggering this, though I have no idea how or why now.

Second, disable all your extensions and re-enable them after a reboot of your mac one at a time to see if one of them triggers this.

Comment: I also have privacy badger installed

Comment: Any luck with disabling all the extensions and then re enabling them one by one?

Comment: @daisy so any new information on this?